# How does this for, in generator work in Python 2.7.x

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm aware of the `for x in list` loop in Python, but I stumbled on a type of generator whose documentation I couldn't find. I found out that the example below only works if the lists inside the list `a` are of length 2, or it gives an unpacking error, so I suspect some kind of 2-tuple or dict-related unpacker may be at play. Can somebody explain to me how this generator syntax works?

```
$ python                                                                                                                                            
Python 2.7.10 (default, Oct 23 2015, 19:19:21) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 7.0.0 (clang-700.0.59.5)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> a = [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]
>>> (b for c, b in a)
<generator object <genexpr> at 0x1071abaa0>
>>> [x for x in (b for c, b in a)]
[2, 4, 6]
```

I ran into it in a project that used this generator in a call to `min`. Originally I thought it was multiple args being passed in, but the syntax made no sense, and testing it individually revealed a generator.

https://github.com/bigbighd604/Python/blob/master/graph/Ford-Fulkerson.py#L59

Comment: [https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/)

Comment: `(b for c, b in a)` is equivalent to `(b for (c, b) in a)`

Comment: You unpack `a` into 2 values `c` and `b` then take only `b`.

Comment: I haven't seen you since Cupertino Junior High... (This is David by the way.)

Comment: A [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#generator-expressions) is like a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) but it doesn't create a list, it returns a generator.  [Expressions, 6.2.4 - 6.2.8](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#displays-for-lists-sets-and-dictionaries)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't be fooled by the comma in `c, b`. In Python, commas -- not parentheses -- are what defines a tuple. Your code is equivalent to `[x for x in (b for (c, b) in a)]`, which iterates through the elements of `a`, assigning `c` to the first element of each two-element list in `a` and `b` to the second, and then assigning `b` to `x`. If `a` had an element that was not a two-element iterable, you would get a `ValueError`.

Comment: Ah, yes it was the comma that threw me off. In the code link I sent, I was also thrown off even more because the generator was passed as an argument to `min`. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Starting from the inside, we are creating a generator expression from list a:

```
a = [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]
```

So, Let us look at that one alone:

```
(b for c, b in a)
```

So, if you look back at list `a`, we have a list of lists, where each sub-list is just two items. So, what is happening here with your generator expression, is that `c, b` are representing each of the unpacked values in your sub-list as a tuple. However, if you look at the expression, we are only taking `b`, which is why the result will end up being:

```
2, 4, 6
```

Then moving outward, we are then just creating a list-comprehension from that generator expression:

```
[x for x in (b for c, b in a)]
```

Ending in a list:

```
[2, 4, 6]
```

Actually, if you are looking to get a list out of that expression, you can just do:

```
list(b for c, b in a)
```